# Selenium Tests Not Running as Expected

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I am cooking up a basic java selenium test using maven and junit.  it looks like this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("version", "17");
    capabilities.setCapability("platform", Platform.MAC);
    this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
            new URL("http://" + authentication.getUsername() + ":" + authentication.getAccessKey() + "@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),
            capabilities);
    driver.get("https://pledgeling.com");
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void testEmailSubmission() throws Exception {
    driver.findElement(By.id("emailAddress")).sendKeys("david@pledgeling.com");
    driver.findElement(By.className("btn-primary")).click();
    Assert.assertEquals(1,1);
}
```

However, when I run my tests with `mvn test`, it doesnt appear that any tests are being run.  How do I fix this?  Why does it say "TestSuite" when there is no class by that name?

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@61dd1c39
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.697 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.597s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Dec 24 12:06:41 PST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Where did you put the source file of this test in your project?

Comment: According to the output TestNG is used for tests, not JUnit. List also your pom.xml file - it will make it easier to investigate.

Comment: Maybe attributes Before, After and Test are from Junit but not TestNG, if i remember correctly you must add TestNG attributes not Junit

Answer (score 0):

David Williams - It looks to me like you are using your Test Suite file incorrectly. You need to a Test Suite file that holds the @Before and @After. Then you create a different Java class and add that under your

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Filename: PlaygroundTestSuite.java
 *
 *
 *
 * How to add a new test class to the suite...
 *   1. Add an import statement for the new test class.
 *   2. Add an entry to the array of test classes.
 *
 */

package *.selenium.test_suites;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

import *.*.*.TestNameBlah;

// Specify a runner class.
@RunWith(Suite.class)
//@formatter:off
// Specify an array of test classes.
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    //Classes to run go here
    TestNameBlah.class,
    }

)
//@formatter:on
public class PlaygroundTestSuite extends BaseSeleniumTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void suiteStart() throws Exception {
        setup();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void suiteEnd() throws Exception {
        logout();
        tearDown();
    }

}
```

Then when you run the Test Suite file it runs the test.